# Access a nested object using a variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, nested, javascript-objects

I am making a game.  The end-user will select a fighter among 12 available fighters.  Let's say they select 'Ryu'.  But they could have selected 'ChunLi'.  The player selection will be stored in the variable 'selectedPlayer'. Now I need to get/access the object (or its members) that matches the user's selection.  I have tried a number ways, including the one shown below, but I get in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Ryu' of undefined."

```
var selectedPlayer = "Ryu";
var Slogan = players[selectedPlayer]['Slogan'];
console.log(Slogan);

var players = {
    Ryu:  {
        Name: "Ryu",
        Country: "Japan",
        Text: "The answer lies in the heart of battle.",
        smImg: "../images/small/ryu.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/ryu.jpg",
        attack: [1,5,10,15,20,25]
    },
    ChunLi: {
        Name: "Chun Li",
        Country: "China",
        Slogan: "Want to see my Kung-Fu? I'll show you.",
        smImg: "../images/small/chunli.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/chunli.jpg",
        attack: [1,4,11,15,21,25]
    }
}
```

I need to be able to get into the 'players' object and access the members of the selected fighers' object.  I could write a bunch of if statements, but that wouldn't be very clean.  Can I do something like this?

```
var playerOne = {
    Name: players.<some variable>.Name,
    Country: players.<some variable>.Country,
    Slogan: players.<some variable>.Slogan,
    smImage: players.<some variable>.smImg,
    lgImage: players.<some variable>.lgImg,
    Attack: players.<some variable>.attack
};

var playerTwo = {
    Name: players.<some variable>.Name,
    Country: players.<some variable>.Country,
    Slogan: players.<some variable>.Slogan,
    smImage: players.<some variable>.smImg,
    lgImage: players.<some variable>.lgImg,
    Attack: players.<some variable>.attack
};
```

Maybe there is a different.  I'm open to anything that works well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the mapping before you access it. Plus, `Ryu` appears to have no `Slogan`.

```
var players = {
    Ryu:  {
        Name: "Ryu",
        Country: "Japan",
        // Shoudldn't this be "Slogan"?
        Text: "The answer lies in the heart of battle.",
        smImg: "../images/small/ryu.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/ryu.jpg",
        attack: [1,5,10,15,20,25]
    },
    ChunLi: {
        Name: "Chun Li",
        Country: "China",
        Slogan: "Want to see my Kung-Fu? I'll show you.",
        smImg: "../images/small/chunli.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/chunli.jpg",
        attack: [1,4,11,15,21,25]
    }
}

var selectedPlayer = "Ryu";
var Slogan = players[selectedPlayer]['Slogan']; 
console.log(Slogan);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work.  The Ryu slogan was a typo that I fixed as I was changing the member name from "text" to "slogan".  Good catch though.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you're referencing `players` before it's defined. Try this:

```
var players = {
    Ryu:  {
        Name: "Ryu",
        Country: "Japan",
        Text: "The answer lies in the heart of battle.",
        smImg: "../images/small/ryu.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/ryu.jpg",
        attack: [1,5,10,15,20,25]
    },
    ChunLi: {
        Name: "Chun Li",
        Country: "China",
        Slogan: "Want to see my Kung-Fu? I'll show you.",
        smImg: "../images/small/chunli.png",
        lgImg: "../images/large/chunli.jpg",
        attack: [1,4,11,15,21,25]
    }
}

var selectedPlayer = "Ryu";
var Slogan = players[selectedPlayer]['Slogan'];
console.log(Slogan);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I realized my error shortly after posting the question.  Thank you for your input.